# Where does JPA generate sequence name?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Ran into a peculiar problem.
I am using JPA + spring to handle my entities. Data are saved in Postgresql.
Tables are generated by JPA. I didn't create any of them.

One of the entity 'Family' has an ID field.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="family_id",nullable = false, columnDefinition = "BIGINT")
private Long id;
```

So, JPA (or hibernate) generate a column with a sequence 'family_id_seq'.
It will query currval('family_id_seq') when new entry are being inserted.
Everything works as expected.

Today when I debugging my program. Suddenly I cannot save any 'Family' using JpaRepository. The error message is currval('family_family_id_seq') does not exist.

Why does my JPA changed the generated seq name? How do I control this?
Which class of Spring JPA is responsible for creating this query?
I want my seq named 'family_id_seq'.
Because other tables' seq is still following that rule.

Comment: Did you change anything in the app or on the database?

Comment: Actually, I found that, if the table is dropped/recreated you can lose access to the sequence and then you receive this error. Check if the sequence itself exists in the DB.

Comment: Using `IDENTITY` under PostgreSQL (which I assume you're using) makes Hibernate leave the field for the database to insert the default. If you want the field to be generated by Hibernate, define it as `bigserial` instead of `bigint`.